# Windows 7 option not visible in Grub after installation of Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Before asking here, I have checked lots of options mentioned here in this portal, but got no success.

So, I was using Windows 7 first, later yesterday I try to dual boot Ubuntu. Now, in Grub it is not showing any option for "Windows 7". This is a [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17840790/) link after running boot repair. Also I have tried

```
sudo fdisk -l

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf8fc78c3

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      206848   227557375   113675264    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       227557376   567171071   169806848    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       567171072   771973119   102401024    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       771975166   976771071   102397953    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       771975168   959994699    94009766   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       959995904   976771071     8387584   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 4004 MB, 4004511744 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486 cylinders, total 7821312 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00ce3852

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     7821311     3909632    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Kindly guide me here.

Comment: Have you tried booting into a Live Ubuntu and use `boot-repair` app? Let me know what else did you try.